# After updating to 1.4.14 Synergie won't work anymore

Tags: windows-xp, synergy

I've updated the server (win7) and the clients (win-xp & osx 10.6.8).

> WindowsXP Log: ERROR: failed to load shell library, synwinxt.dll is
>   missing or invalid

The DLL lies in the same folder as synergie. I replaced it twice and updating to 1.4.15 didn't help either.

On OS X after starting synergie in a terminal, I tried to connect to the server, but freezes.

On Win7 I got just: `"accepted client connection"` and `"new client disconnected"`

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly my problem with Synergy and it's the problem I have EVERY time I update it.

Synergy locks that file somehow - so when it's own uninstall package tries to uninstall the old version it fails, and it can't write the new version when it installs the new version.

It seems to be the ever-present problem with Synergy - that it doesn't relinquish control of files properly from it's service.

It's an embarrassing shambles and always costs me a couple of hours trying to figure it out when I do eventually get around to installing the latest version.

One of my Win 7 Pro machines eventually let go of the file on reboot. The other one I had to rename the file.

You could also go to task manager> services and stop Synergy then uninstall it, then try and remove any files in the Program Files/Synergy folder.

Then install the new version.